# implicit conversion Option[T] to String

Tags: scala

I am trying to use implicit to convert option value in scala to String but somehow its working. Here is my syntax -

```
object ToStringParser{
  implicit def optionAnyToString[T](input: Option[T]):String = {
    input match {
      case Some(i) => i.toString
      case None => "NULL"
    }
  }
}
```

And I am using it like -

```
import domain.processors.ToStingParser._
println(submitDate)
```

But this is always printing -

```
Some(2016-08-02T17:55:03.000-04:00)
```

How do we have implicit for Options

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is that `println` accepts a parameter of type `Any`, so it has no way to know that you want it to use your implicit conversion, you have to tell it somehow that you want a `String`, rather than an `Option`.

This would work: `println(submitDate: String)`, 
and so would this: `def puts(s: String) = println(s); puts(submitDate)`.

But it really doesn't seem to save you much compared to just doing it explicitly in this case:

```
println(submitDate.getOrElse("NULL"))
```

which would be a lot clearer to the reader.

Comment: Getting error in both cases - 

[error]  found   : Option[org.joda.time.DateTime]
[error]  required: String
[error]     println(submitDate: String)



Case 2

[error]  found   : Option[org.joda.time.DateTime]
[error]  required: String
[error]     println(put(submitDate))

Comment: Also to your point using println(submitDate.getOrElse("NULL")) , I need to do this for around 50 string and then join them with a delimiter. I want to add these in Seq and then mkString with DELIMITER

Comment: must be something wrong with your import. You should not be getting any errors. I just tried it in repl to be sure - it works fine. 
As to joining 50 strings or whatnot, it doesn't change the fact that you are not getting much from your implicit convertion:
`seqOfOptions.map(_.getOrElse("NULL").toString).mkString(DELIMITER)` will do fine.

Comment: Cool.. I like it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that `println` takes an `Any` on whatever is passed to it so that your implicit conversion never kicks in (it just calls `.toString` on its parameters).

however, if you do this:

```
def f(x: String) = x
println(f(Some(1)))
println(f(None))
```

You'll see that your implicit conversion is actually working great.

Answer (score 1):

@Dima is right. I just want to expand on the implicit mechanism.

`println(x)` accepts argument of type `String` as well as `Any`.

In your case, `println(x: Any)` is being called since `x` is of type `Option[String]` and eventually `x.toString()` is being called and printed. Hence the `Some(...)` result.

You need to enforce the call to the `println(x: String)` version that will force the implicit conversion from `Option[T]` to `String`.

Therefore you want:

```
import domain.processors.ToStringParser._

val submitDate: Option[DateTime] = // ...
println(submitDate: String)
```